# rails server command does not make a project run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I forked and downnloaded a project from GitHub to nitrous.io but the command

```
rails server
```

will not work and as a result I cannot check that the project works.

Comment: show **Gemfile** of your rails project, and the error of rails run.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands before running the rails server:

```
$bundle install
$rake db:setup
```

Not guaranteed to work but it's a start.